# Eclipse RCP Spring integration error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm facing issue, integrating Spring in my eclipse rcp project. Basically, to avoid confusion, I've created a simple Hello RCP With a view, created a Plugin from existing jars(for spring Jars), added this project to Hello RCP with a view as a dependency, I've placed applicationContext.xml file in my src folder of the RCP project.
  It always throws FileNotFoundException when I place applicationContext.xml in the src folder. As a workaround I've also tried using absolute path

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("E:/applicationContext.xml");
```

This approach thorws ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class with bean Name .....

for a normal Java application it works for me. How can I do that, where to place applicationContext.xml in Eclipse RCP, are there any simple tutorials for integrating spring with eclipse rcp. How to get rid of this issue and use spring in my application.

Comment: Just some loud thinking: so for me it seems that the Spring classpath is not the same as the RCP classpath. Hence it does not see your bean.

Comment: Checked this already? 
http://java.smartit.info/documentation/howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring DM is an option for integrating spring and osgi. expose spring beans as services in osgi.

Comment: here is step by step integration http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2008/jw-04-osgi2.html?page=5